# installation of rpy2 on python 2.6

Tags: python, centos, python-2.6, rpy2, centos5

I need to install from source the package `rpy2` on a machine running python 2.6 (old CentOS release). The current version of rpy2 is 2.5, and it's only compatible on python >= 2.7.

From the [official documentation](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/overview.html#requirements), I checked the last few versions and found out that `2.2` is the last one that runs on Python 2.6. Too bad that it won't install:

```
# python26 setup.py build install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 441, in <module>
    [os.path.join('doc', 'source', 'rpy2_logo.png')])],
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 134, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 994, in run_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 117, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "setup.py", line 152, in finalize_options
    config += get_rconfig(r_home, about)
  File "setup.py", line 312, in get_rconfig
    rc = RConfig.from_string(rconfig, allow_empty = allow_empty)
  File "setup.py", line 272, in from_string
    + '\nin string\n' + string)
ValueError: Invalid substring
-fopenmp
in string
-Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp  -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR -lrt -ldl -lm
```

**SOLUTION**:

I needed to install a previous version of R (2.12 or 2.13), as mentioned in [the docs](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/overview.html#requirements)

Comment: To use an older rpy2, you might have to also use an equally old version of R. As an alternative, compiling a recent Python from source should be considered...

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! I installed the version of R with which rpy 2.2 is compatible, as described in the link I provided, and it all worked.